# capture returncode of python script running within the container

Tags: python, bash, docker

I'm creating a make-release script where the full application is prepared for deployment on the machine where it is needed. It should be able to be build on a standard linux build machine (with docker)
The thing is that I struggle to find a way to make a single python script independed from the build machine.

```
"""Return hash of the key, used for prometheus web-portal access configuration"""

import sys
try:
    import bcrypt
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)

args = sys.argv

if len(args) == 2:
    try:
        PASSWORD = str(args[1])
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(PASSWORD.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())
        print(hashed_password.decode())
        sys.exit(0)
    except (IndexError, SystemError, ValueError, RuntimeError, UnicodeError) as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)

else:
    print('not enough arguments given')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Depending on the return code the print is either a hash or an error code.
It is therefor important to have the return code to handle the script different.

```
# get hashed key for prometheus
HASHED_SECRET=$(python3 src/generate_prometheus_passhash.py ${PROMETHEUS_WEB_PASS})
RETURN_CODE=$?

if [ ${RETURN_CODE} == 0 ]; then
  <Use hash>
else
  echo "error: ${HASHED_SECRET}"
  exit 1;
fi
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

EDIT:
In summary.
The python script has to run in a docker container to prevent library dependencies on the host machine.
I want to get both the return code (1 or 0 from the script) as the print (stdout) out of the docker container where the python script runs in.
The calls should be done via bash.

Comment: I don't understand the actual question. In which respect does your script behave differently from what you expect?

Comment: I do not understand. Are you asking how to get returncode from a process running inside the container __or__ are you asking how to exit from a shell script __or__ are you asking how to write a a generic deployment Python script?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `||` logic to set a bad hash in `HASH` if the return code is not `0`, and check for the value of `$HASH` with a `if` statement:

`script.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

args = sys.argv

if (len(args) < 2):
    exit(1)
else:
    print("ABCDEFG")
    exit(0)
```

`test.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Trying something that will fail"
HASH=$(python3 script.py || echo "BAD-HASH")
echo "HASH: $HASH"

echo "Trying something that will work"
HASH=$(python3 script.py a b c || echo "BAD-HASH")
echo "HASH: $HASH"
```

Output

```bash
$ ./test.sh
Trying something that will fail
HASH: BAD-HASH
Trying something that will work
HASH: ABCDEFG
```